# Compare dates of different data types

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to join two tables for some data validation, and am attempting to join them on the two date fields that are of different types.  I am currently using HIVE and I am creating two tables then importing each file into it's own table as it is coming from two seperate sources.  I am assign both field types as strings.  However, when I do a select * from each table this is what I get

```
t1.asgn_dt = 20-MAY-19
t2.trans_dt = 20190520
```

I have tried cast them both as strings, converting to dates among other things. What is the best way to convert, and which field, from which table would I change to allow me to compare the two that would show they are both equal.

Comment: I have even tried using the from_unix with the to_Date function but it turns every month into January and returns 2010-01-05 when the input month is 20100305.

Comment: Every combination of convert, cast and from_unix time I have tried returns null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(<col>, <format>))`, so:

For `'20-MAY-19'`:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20-MAY-19' , 'dd-MMM-yy'))
```

For `'20190520'`:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20190520' , 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Comment: I attempted this and all I got back was blank data. `select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(trans_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
from table2`

Answer (score 0):

Use **`From_unixtime and unix_timestamp`** functions to convert your data into one consistent format and then **use those expressions** in your join condition.

**Example:**

**`1. For dd-MMM-yyformat:`**

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("20-MAY-19","dd-MMM-yy"),"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**`Result:`**

```
2019-05-20
```

**`2. For yyyyMMdd format:`**

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("20190520","yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

**`Result:`**

```
2019-05-20
```